Scatter instances within plane borders and avoid overlapping
as the title says, I was wondering if there's a way to scatter instances randomly along the face of a plan BUT without trepassing the border of the same emitter. Together with this, I would like to avoid the overlapping of the instances.
I have some building to scatter along a grid of streets (basically, a plan with array modifier repeated to create isolates of nine blocks each), and I've tried different classical solutions so far (scaling the plan dimensions, weight paint, moving instances' origins), but without great results.
I can show you the grid together with the houses in x-ray mode.
Many thanks for any suggestion you'd like to submit!



Do you want to delete or to scale down overlapping instances ?

Thanks! If possible, work by difference as a boolean, but I guess you need to create cages around each building. If not possible, simply delete
